# Trouble getting rails to work after some system changes - possibly symbolic links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I think it maybe something to do with me setting up some symbollic links that is stopping rails from seeing the right version of Ruby. It keeps going back to version 1.8. Normally been easy with RVM to move between different versions of ruby, but not any more. What's your thoughts?

```
steve@steve-laptop:~/Ruby/MyRuby$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)
   global
=> rails3

steve@steve-laptop:~/Ruby/MyRuby$ rvm use 1.9.3-p194@rails3 --default
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194 with gemset rails3
steve@steve-laptop:~/Ruby/MyRuby$ gem install rails
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 2: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3") 
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 3: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global")
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 4: +: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 12: require: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 13: require: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 14: require: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 16: required_version: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 18: unless: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 19: abort: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 20: end: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 22: args: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 24: begin: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 25: Gem::GemRunner.new.run: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 26: rescue: command not found
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem: line 27: exit: e.exit_code: numeric argument required
steve@steve-laptop:~/Ruby/MyRuby$ sudo gem install rails
[sudo] password for steve: 
Successfully installed rails-3.2.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.7...
steve@steve-laptop:~/Ruby/MyRuby$ rails new deploy
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:22

steve@steve-laptop:~/Ruby/MyRuby$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
steve@steve-laptop:~/Ruby/MyRuby$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)
   global
=> rails3

steve@steve-laptop:~/Ruby/MyRuby$ rails -v
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:22
```

Comment: what is the output of `which rails`

Answer (score 1):

You should never need to use sudo with rvm, please go to [rvm site](https://rvm.io/) for instructions how to use rvm. In case of any problems please join me(mpapis) on #rvm on irc freenode servers.

It looks like your ruby installation is busted, gist: `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem` ... but most likely reinstallation should fix it:

```
rvm get head 
rvm reload
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```